# Convert JavaScript array of 2 element arrays into object key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What is the fastest algorithm for getting from something like this:

```
var array = [ [1,'a'], [2,'b'], [3,'c'] ];
```

to something like this:

```
Object { 1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c" }
```

so far this is what i've come up with:

```
function objectify(array) {
    var object = {};
    array.forEach(function(element) {
        object[element[0]] = element[1];
    });
    return object;
}
```

which works fine, but it seems kind of clumsy. Is there a better way? Would something like [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce) work and would that be any faster?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could indeed use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
function objectify(array) {
    return array.reduce(function(p, c) {
         p[c[0]] = c[1];
         return p;
    }, {});
}
```

where `p` is the result of the previous iteration, initially `{}`, and `c` is the current element of the array.

It's unlikely to be any faster than `array.forEach`, but it is IMHO cleaner.  I don't believe there's any simpler implementation than this.

NB: a function to do exactly this already exists in the [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#object) library: `_.object(array)`

Answer (score 34):

You can use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert an `Array` to an `Object`:

```js
var array = [
  [1, 'a'],
  [2, 'b'],
  [3, 'c']
];
var object = Object.fromEntries(array);
console.log(object);
```

Comment: This is the "correct" answer, and much nicer than the `reduce` approach. Only use `reduce` if you need to target very old browsers (eg IE)

Comment: What an elegant way of getting things done. This code snippet does the job without any further complications.

Answer (score 9):

Terse version using modern syntax:

```
let objectify = a => a.reduce( (o,[k,v]) => (o[k]=v,o), {} );
```

I use this technique as part of a terse query string parser:

```
// Converts "?foo=bar&j=1&go" into { foo:'bar', j:'1', go:true }
function parseQueryString(qs) {
    var q = decodeURIComponent;
    return qs.replace(/^\?/,'').split('&').map(s => s.split('='))
             .reduce((o,[k,v]) => (o[q(k)] = v?q(v):true, o), {});
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly for my use case. I consider myself pretty proficient in ESXXXX but I can't quite figure out how that lambda is working. Specifically the `(o[k]=v,o)` part. Any insights?

Also, thanks for sharing this gem. :-)

Comment: @KyleFarris it's using the comma operator to perform the assignment into the map, and then return `o` itself.

Answer (score 7):

Lodash has a [`_.fromPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/#fromPairs) method that does exactly that.

From the documentation:

```
_.fromPairs([['a', 1], ['b', 2]]);
// => { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the entire thing within [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), like this

```
function objectify(array) {
    return array.reduce(function(result, currentArray) {
        result[currentArray[0]] = currentArray[1];
        return result;
    }, {});
}

console.log(objectify([ [1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c'] ]));
# { '1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'c' }
```

We are just accumulating the key-value pairs in the `result` object and finally the result of `reduce` will be the `result` object and we are returning it as the actual result.