# Initialize Javascript Dictionary From Array of Pairs

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, dictionary

I have an array that looks something like this: `[["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"]]`. I want a dictionary that looks like this: `{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}`. In Python, I could just pass the array to the  `dict` initializer. Is there some equivalent way of doing this in Javascript, or am I stuck initializing an empty dictionary and adding the key/value pairs to the dictionary one at a time?

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454655/convert-javascript-array-of-2-element-arrays-into-object-key-value-pairs

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald: Nice one, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually really easy with `Array#reduce`:

```
var obj = yourArray.reduce(function(obj, entry) {
    obj[entry[0]] = entry[1];
    return obj;
}, {});
```

`Array#reduce` loops through the entries in the array, passing them repeatedly into a function along with an "accumulator" you initialize with a second argument.

Or perhaps `Array#forEach` would be clearer and more concise in this case:

```
var obj = {};
yourArray.forEach(function(entry) {
    obj[entry[0]] = entry[1];
});
```

Or there's the simple `for` loop:

```
var obj = {};
var index, entry;
for (index = 0; index < yourArray.length; ++index) {
    entry = yourArray[index];
    obj[entry[0]] = entry[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `pairs` variable, you can use a `map()` function workaround (not very elegant, as map is supposed to be used in other scope) :

```
var convertedDict = {};
pairs.map(function(pair) {
    convertedDict[pair[0]] = pair[1];
});
```