# Convert object key-value pairs to a series of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Javascript. I have a Javascript object like so:

```
s = {"Toothless":"Dragon","Foo":"Bar"};
```

I need to convert it into a series of arrays, like so:

```
out = [["Toothless","Dragon"],["Foo","Bar"]];
```

This is the reverse of what is discussed in [Convert JavaScript array of 2 element arrays into object key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454655/convert-javascript-array-of-2-element-arrays-into-object-key-value-pairs). A JQuery solution is acceptable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can map over the items to achieve this:

```js
    s = {"Toothless":"Dragon","Foo":"Bar"};
    var out = Object.keys(s).map(function(data){
        return [data,s[data]];
    });
    console.log(out);
```

Comment: in one line: `let out = Object.keys(s).map(data => [data, s[data]]);`

Answer (score 5):

```
let s = {"Toothless":"Dragon","Foo":"Bar"};

let out = Object.entries(s);
```

and you get `out` as an array of small arrays,
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = {"Toothless":"Dragon","Foo":"Bar"};
var out = [];
for (var key in s){
    out.push([key, s[key]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jQuery.

```js
var tempArr = [];
s = {"Toothless":"Dragon","Foo":"Bar"};
$.each(s,function(i,v){
 tempArr.push([i,v]);
});
```